# Securely Upload data to Server from HTML Form

Tags: javascript, php, security, server

My website allows users to input and upload 2 things:

1. Their name - which they type into a textfield in an `HTML form`
2. And a photo - which they upload from their computer also using this same `form`.

Upon hitting "submit" my `Javascript` code calls a `PHP` script sitting on my server, that `PHP` script takes that data and writes it into a `JSON` file, puts that file in the right folder, also puts the image where it needs to go - and it all works perfectly thus far.

However, it just dawned on me that *anyone* reading my Javascript code can find the URL of my PHP script - which means they can then copy-paste that URL directly into the browser - and wreak all sorts of havoc.

Obviously I need to go about all this in a different way.

Should I just not use PHP for this? If so, what other languages or platforms are available for me to do what I just described - in a way that's impossible to hack?

Or is there a way to obfuscate the URL of my PHP script so that no one can copy-paste it into the browser address bar?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

================================

UPDATE:

Here’s my PHP script:

```
<?php

$tokenID = $_POST["tokenIDNum"];
$fileName = "TokenMetadata/token". $tokenID .".json";
$userName = $_POST["userName"];
$imageURL = $_POST["userImageURL"];

// Log out for verification:
echo "Here's what I got so far:<br/>";
echo "tokenID: " .$tokenID ."<br/>";
echo "userName: " .$userName ."<br/>";
echo "imageURL: " .$imageURL ."<br/>";


// CREATE AND SAVE THE NEW METADATA-FILE:
$newMetadataFile = fopen($fileName, "wb");
if( $newMetadataFile == false ) {
    // Do debugging or logging here:
    echo "OPPS! We got an 'fopen' problem!";
}
else {
    $contentString = "{\r\n";
    $contentString = $contentString. '   "name" : “Fun Token # ' . $tokenID . '",';
    $contentString = $contentString. "\r\n";
    $contentString = $contentString. '   "description" : "Another token from our FUN Collection.",';
    $contentString = $contentString. "\r\n";
    $contentString = $contentString. '   "image" : "' .$imageURL;
    $contentString = $contentString. "\r\n}";

    fwrite($newMetadataFile, $contentString);
    fclose($newMetadataFile);
}
    
// or die("Unable to open file!");
// $myfile = fopen("token.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

?>
```

When I copy-paste the URL for this script into my browser - which is what I worry some bad actor might do - it creates a new EMPTY `JSON` file - and that's without me passing any arguments into that URL. So I'm pretty sure right now someone could not only create new phoney `JSON` files in this manner, but also *rewrite* existing ones with false data if they were to pass values for my arguments.

What I need to know is if it's even possible to prevent bad actors from doing this - or if I have to go about this in some totally different way?

My understanding is that if I add `SESSION` and perhaps `CAPTCH` I might be ok? (Obviously, I'm no PHP expert.)

Would love any thoughts/suggestions regarding that - before I spend hours going down *that* rabbit hole.

Comment: Anyone sufficiently sophisticated to read your JavaScript code will be able to use the browser tools to determine the URL on your server. The usual way to handle this is to require your users to register before uploading, and have your PHP script check that the uploader is registered before accepting uploads.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular  So you're saying that if I *REQUIRE* users to register - which I'm assuming means I'll then be giving each one of them a unique password - then if someone else tries to copy-paste the URL of my PHP script directly into their browser and run it from there, then I can have my PHP *not run* because that run-attempt would be lacking such valid password - and that would solve everything?

Comment: Well it depends what you mean by "everything"...for all we know you might have other security issues too. But if you put the appropriate code into the PHP to ensure that the request has a valid login session before it processes the upload, then it would stop any old random access to the script yes. Or alternatively if you just want to stop automated bots or client-side scripts from sending random data in large amounts then implement a captcha in your form and PHP so that only humans can use it. Depends on your exact requirements and what exact threat you're trying to deal with.

Comment: `which means they can then copy-paste that URL directly into the browser `...that would generate a GET request, but I expect your JS does a POST to it. So what "havoc" exactly do you expect from a GET? Of course there are other tools than a browser for making HTTP requests which can automate POSTs (or any other type of request) so your concern is legitimate but the direction you're thinking it would come from is slightly misplaced, I would think.

Comment: `Should I just not use PHP for this`...the nature of this type of threat has nothing to do with which server side language you use to program with.

Comment: `Or is there a way to obfuscate the URL of my PHP script `...no. and anyway security by obscurity is not security. It merely delays the inevitable. Add something which actually checks whether it seems each request to be legitimate or not (see the suggestions we made earlier).

Comment: P.s. on another note, why are you storing this data in JSON? A database would almost certainly be a lot more efficient

Comment: @ADyson 
Your question regarding my reason for using JSON is a good one, and the answer has to do with this:
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721Metadata

Basically the standard way of providing metadata for Ethereum NFT's to the outside world - meaning the numerous platforms and apps that work with and display NFT’s - is through a JSON file. And there’s a very specific format you’re supposed to follow when you write this JSON file.

Comment: @ADyson. So while you’re totally right that the info my users enter & upload should be stored in a database, ultimately it’ll still need to be served to the world as a JSON file - on a per-token basis. So if you have 10,000 tokens and some platform or wallet-app needs to display token # 5072, you’ll need to provide it with a URL for a single JSON file that has the pertinent info for that token. And that actual URL will probably be something like:  https://www.YourDomain.com/TokenMetdata/token5072.json
And token#395 would require this:
https://www.YourDomain.com/TokenMetdata/token395.json

Comment: @ADyson  For security, I do have Firewall (and an SSL) - but I definitely need to somehow prevent bad actors from misbehaving.

Comment: @ADyson  When I just paste the URL of my PHP file into my browser - it creates a new empty `JSON` file. That's without me even passing any values through the URL. So _that's_ what I'm looking to prevent.

Comment: @ADyson I just update my question with the PHP code I'm using. Let me know if any of this extra info gives you a better idea regarding the best way to secure what I'm trying to do.  It sounds like I definitely need to add `SESSION` and perhaps a `CAPTCHA`?